# Wordpress menu can not be clicked in mobile site

Tags: wordpress, menu

I've tried all the solutions from stackoverflow and wordpress stack exchange, but havn't succeeded.

**Problem :**
I've updated my wordpress site to latest version `word press 4.9.5`, I don't know that after updating wordpress or what causes menu to not being clickable..checking in inspector, the ul of nav menu is there but it has css `display:none`..May be it should be any script or js issue?

**What I've Tried:**

1. Deactivates all the plugins
2. linking the script file of twentyeleven theme(if I've messed up with any script)
3. Installed the `WDES Responsive Mobile Menu` plugin
4. Updated all plugins and themes

**Desktop site's Menu screenshot:**

[image]

**Mobile site's Menu screenshot:** (*menu is not clickable*)

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

**console shows these errors:**

```
ReferenceError: lightbox_init is not defined
ReferenceError: omShortcodes is not defined
```

Comment: you have multible js errors...are you using any plugin that changes the order of js-files? disable minify for debugging...

Comment: @Tobias  I'm not aware about that specific plugin..but I tried to disable all the plugins..but it could not help..and what is this minify? any plugin?

Comment: look at your last line in source code...<!--HTML minified, size saved 9.69%. From 479634 bytes, now 433162 bytes--> i think this is a plugin, and many of this plugins make problems

Comment: I don't have any plugin which minifies the HTML :( (or may be I'm not aware of it)..Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this script into your header or footer file.Hope this will help you

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $( ".mobile-header-menu-control" ).click(function() {
 $( ".mobile-header-menu-container" ).toggle();
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Works like charm..Thanks a lot.